# iPhone app main view does not rotate but need to rotate for when a UIWebView is called?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I have a TabBar application that I would like to keep in portrait mode but when streaming video via UIWebView I would like to add support to rotate to landscape in order to go full screen.  Is this possible?  The layout of my app does not look too appealing in landscape hence the reason for wanting to stay in portrait mode.  But watching the video in portrait mode is not appealing at all if you cannot go fullscreen.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
    if (_isPlaying) return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    if (_isPlaying && UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)){
        // Hide tabBar Or Go fullscreen
    }
    else {
        // show tabBar 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @NJones.  My rootController is my TabBarViewController and the orientation is being handled by the app delegate.  My first tab or view in the app has several buttons when pressed will launch the MPMoviePlayerController.  I'm a bit confused on how to handle the orientation for the moviePlayerController and/or using a UIWebView via app delegate.